# Autocomplete city list query taking too much time to load on huge city table

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I am having a city table with nearly 1,600,000 records. I have a autocomplete text box and I have the query to fetch the city data, country data as follows:

```
SELECT m.idmetrocenter, m.idcountry, m.metrocentername, 
c.idcountry, c.countryname FROM metrocenter m 
INNER JOIN country c ON m.idcountry = c.idcountry 
WHERE (m.metrocentername like "ap%" OR c.countryname like "ap%") 
ORDER BY m.metrocentername, c.countryname 
LIMIT 10
```

This query takes more time to respond and its its response time is almost 110 sec. 
I have created indexes on idmetrocenter, idcountry, metrocentername, countryname. The response even then is so poor.

Can anyone help me out to make this output achieved faster. I am currently using doctrine. If some one can let me know solution in doctrine will be even better.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First try to `explain` your query and see if indexes are effectively used:

`mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT m.idmetrocenter AS m__idmetrocenter, m.idcountry AS m__idcountry, m.metrocentername AS m__metrocentername, c.idcountry AS c__idcountry, c.countryname AS c__countryname FROM metrocenter m INNER JOIN country c ON m.idcountry = c.idcountry WHERE (m.metrocentername like "ap%" OR c.countryname like "ap%") ORDER BY m.metrocentername, c.countryname LIMIT 10 \G`

Second:
Try to change the LIKE statement to a full-text search (`MATCH/AGAINST` )
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 0):

Beside using FTS as Francesco suggested, you could also use Doctrines built-in [search behaviour](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/searching/pl). This simply build up an index with all words for defined columns and make them accessible in an efficient and quick manner.

If you can't built up/make us of FTS, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing [JOINS](http://ezinearticles.com/?What-is-a-Cartesian-Join?&id=3560672) you have to do [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). That is very expensive and you should avoid it.

In this day and age you should forget about [data normalization](http://kottke.org/04/10/normalized-data). As  Cal Henderson From Flickr says: "[normalised data is for sissies](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0BwZmyTpNvL8uZTZlZmU0ODEtODllNS00YmEzLWJhYmMtNDE3NGE1YWE3YjJm&hl=en_GB&authkey=CN_Sk5EI)" (Slide 27 of 41). It makes searching faster. These slides are really good and have a lot of good information. So on slide 24 of 41 they say they did not use LIKE because it is slow. They use FULLTEXT indexes(slide 25 of 41).

Also I think you should cache [the data(autocomplete) in memory](http://antirez.com/post/autocomplete-with-redis.html) using redis to speed up your site. If you can't compile the source(redis and if you could compile [phpredis](https://github.com/owlient/phpredis) or else just plain php version => [predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis)). Then you could even use [Redis To Go](http://redistogo.com/)'s free plan. Redis is [fast!](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks).